# Canonical workflow for python packaging and GitHub

Tags: python, git, packaging, pypi

I'm working on a solo project which I published to PyPi. Now that I've installed it with pip rather than using it from my git repo, what is the best-practice for continuing development ?

I've tried two approaches till now:

1. The naivete: edit scripts in `site-packages` folder, test them, once finalized, copy to repo and push( and build, publish etc)
2. The doppelganger: make a (sparse) repo to track the scripts in `site packages`, push whenever. Once ready to publish, go to the folder with the full repo, pull and then build>publish.

Now, 1. is too clunky, while 2. leaves me thoroughly unsatisfied. I was thinking of using bash tricks to streamline 2., but I thought that the sages here might have something much more streamlined, so I ask.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development you will still want to get and edit source code from the git repository, not from `PyPi`.

For example, if your git repository lived under `.../src/myproject/`, I would run `pip install .` inside `myproject`. This emulates an installation in the exact same way that `pip install myproject=={version}` would if it downloaded from PyPi. (copies the code to `site-packages`)

Even better for development is `pip install -e .`, which sets a symbolic link from `site-packages` back to your source directory. So while it looks like your project is installed in your venv, it's actually just using the source code from your `git` repo folder.

In general the downloads from PyPi are for *users* of your script, not contributors.

Let me know in the comments if you want me to expand on any of this.

Comment: It works great, but, could you suggest a reading perhaps ? I'm curious as to how often it updates, and how exactly it does that. Does pip check for updates every time it needs to import ?? Thank You again

Comment: @codesPliff this is probably a pretty good collection of guides -- https://packaging.python.org/guides/

Comment: Damn i had found just the one page official docs, but that page, wow, i was just thinking about how to automate building on github and now its done thanks to that respurce. Cheers